# SSH error: Temporary failure in name resolution on mpi run

Tags: linux, ssh, parallel-processing

I have 6 computers (4 cores each and identical in hardwares) with static IPs and need to run NAMD computational chemistry software parallel using OpenMPI. So I

1. installed SSH and OpenMPI (on mint 18)
2. place the executable file in /bin on all computers
3. set up passwordless SSH (I can access all 4 slave computers without password from master machine)

However it works on 3 computers and for others it gives

```
 mpiuser@master ~/Desktop/apoa1-16 $ mpiexec -np 16 --hostfile mpi-hostfile namd2 apoa1.namd > apoa1.log  
 ssh: Could not resolve hostname slave32: Temporary failure in name resolution
 ssh: Could not resolve hostname slave27: Temporary failure in name resolution  
 [master:04223] 1 more process has sent help message help-errmgr-base.txt / failed-daemon-launch  
 [master:04223] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

my /etc/hosts of master computer looks like this

```
127.0.0.1   localhost  
#127.0.1.1  master  
172.18.112.78 master  
#Cluster Host Names  
172.18.112.75 slave25  
172.18.112.76 slave26  
172.18.112.77 slave27  
172.18.112.82 slave32  
172.18.112.81 slave31
```

ssh slavexx works fine

my mpi-hostfile looks like this

```
localhost slots=4  
slave25 slots=4  
slave26 slots=4  
slave27 slots=4  
slave31 slots=4  
slave32 slots=4
```

slave25 and slave26 works fine (max 12 processors, mpiexec -np 16), but more than that give `ssh: Could not resolve hostname slavexx: Temporary failure in name resolution` error. it is so weired since i can ping,ssh all 5 computers without a problem.

anyone have an idea to resolve this?

and one other thing, these machines are cloned. so I changed the computer hostname lately and reinstalled SSH and OpenMPI.

**UPDATE:** just now I figured out that only the first three in the `mpi-hostfile` used for the MPI run. for others above error pops!

Comment: Can you ping the other hosts which you have problems with? You need to be sure that their hostnames can be resolved. Can you also check for your /etc/resolv.conf file
Try to remove DNS server there so only your hosts file will be used

Comment: Yes, I can ping others and found the solution!
I need to enable passwordless ssh in all machines, including slave machines. It solves the problem.